# How do I debug a mobile Safari crash that works on iPhone 5, but not 4S

Tags: javascript, ios, ios5, ios6, mobile-webkit

I'm not even sure where to begin. Page loads fine on my 5, but not my 4S. Instead it crashes the browser to the home screen.

Without sharing the specific URL, can you point me in the right direction to debug this?

There are no discernible errors in Firebug or other debugging tools on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be seeing a crash report in Xcode organizer and an exception on the command line. Since this is an Apple app you should report this as a Radar.

Comment: So this is a web site, not an iOS app.  But are you saying I can run the web page in Xcode just the same and look for crash reports there?

Comment: No. But you see the crash reports of ALL apps in Xcode organizer if you connect sour device via USB. And you see the console output.

Comment: Gotcha, so connect my iPhone 4S to Xcode via USB and view console output.  Didn't know I could do that.  Thanks.

Comment: If indeed Safari crashes there will also be a crash report for it visible in Organizer as well. Since you don't have the symbols it is not much good to you, but if you attached that to a bug report to Apple they can tell why the ceash is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

Does your 5 have a newer version of safari?

Use the iOS simulator if you have it, and then try running with different versions of safari, you can get a log output from it, especially if you are using dashcode, otherwise I think it is in the system logger. That is, if you have a Mac.